# Laravel shows 'index of' page only on certain routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've noticed some people have had similar issues to this, but the issue has been to do with their vhosts and document roots, but most of the URLS on my site seem to be working fine.

For example, if I create the following routes

```
Route::get('cases', function(){
    dd('here');
});

Route::get('bookings', function(){
    dd('there');
});
```

`my.local/bookings` works absolutely fine, but `my.local/cases` just shows me the **index of /cases** page.

I have rolled back my code to a time it was definitely working, but its still returning the **index of /cases** page.

Why would laravel randomly stop some routes working?

Heres what i've looked at so far

- Rolling my code back to a working state
- Dumping composer autoload
- Checking `php artisan route:list` to make sure it exists
- Trying a server alias to see if a local IP would work instead
- Changing my PHP version

It just wont show me this one page?

Any ideas?! Its driving me mad!

**Note - `/cases/create` works fine, my index `/` page works fine, it just seems to be a `GET` request to `/cases`**

Comment: wich version laravel are you using ?

Comment: How do you load the url ? are you using a link <a>Link</a> ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is the default `.htaccess` rewrite rule:

```
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The two conditions define that the request should only be forwarded to `index.php` (and therefore Laravel) if there isn't an actual file or folder matching the URL.

It seems like there is a `cases` folder inside `public`, so Laravel will not handle requests to that folder.

You can either rename the `public/cases` folder / the route or remove the first `RewriteCond` condition. But removing it might have unintended side-effects.

Comment: But it was working previously, and just stopped. I noticed it went a bit funny as soon as I started to use the `File` Facade and tried to move a document. What do you mean "rename the folder / the route" sorry?

Comment: Is it possible that when you moved the document you created the `public/cases` folder? Right now the `RewriteRule` will not pass the request to Laravel. It should work if you rename either the `cases` folder or the `cases` route to no longer be be identical. Or just move `cases` to a subfolder.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you!